# Printing Two Dimensional Associative Array in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, associative-array

I have created associative array but when I try to print it in for loop, I don't get all the values. I tried to look up for an sample but there's no example which prints the two dimensional associative array. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A links
links["A",0]="linkA1"
links["A",1]="linkA2"
links["B",0]="linkB1"
links["B",1]="linkB2"
links["C",0]="linkC1"
links["C",1]="linkC2"
links["C",2]="linkC2"

#echo "${links["A",0]}"
#echo "${links["A",1]}"
#echo "${links["B",0]}"

for i in ${#links[@]} ; do
  echo "key: $i"
  j=0 
  while [ "${j}" -le 2 ]; do
    echo "value: ${links["${i}","${j}"]}"
    j=$(( $j + 1 ))
  done
done
```

Comment: Bash doesn't have 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: This is a 1-dimensional array, the commas are literal parts of the keys.

Comment: What do you expect `for i in ${#links[@]}` to do? `${#links[@]}` returns the number of elements in the array, not a list of keys. So this is just `for i in 7`

Comment: Use `${links[@]}` to get a list of all the keys. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91943/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-indexes-ids-keys-on-a-bash-associative-array-vari

Comment: But there's no built-in way to get just `A`, `B`, `C`.

Comment: @Barmar you may have wanted to say "Use `${!links[@]}` to get a list of all the *keys*". :)